# CSS3 : increase tooltip div height to upwards

Tags: html, css

I have a text with text-overflow:ellipsis. When I hover on text then I get a tooltip div with the whole text.

but when text is too much then the tooltip div height is increasing downwards instead of upwards.

```css
.added_caption_div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.added_caption_div span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 180px;
  max-width: 190px;
}

.added_caption_div .caption_tooltip_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  width: 185px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.added_caption_div .caption_tooltip_div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.added_caption_div:hover .caption_tooltip_div {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="added_caption_div">
  <span>Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</span>
  <div class="caption_tooltip_div text-center">Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `top: -40px;` give `bottom: 100%;`

```
.added_caption_div .caption_tooltip_div {
   bottom: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.added_caption_div {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

.added_caption_div span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 180px;
  max-width: 190px;
}

.added_caption_div .caption_tooltip_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -105px;
  width: 185px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.added_caption_div .caption_tooltip_div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}


.added_caption_div:hover span{
top:35px;
position:absolute;
}
.added_caption_div:hover{
top:100px;
}
.added_caption_div:hover .caption_tooltip_div {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="added_caption_div">
  <span>Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</span>
  <div class="caption_tooltip_div text-center">Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rishi now check it